# I need to parameterize jenkins job to run X times

Tags: ant, command-line, jenkins, jmeter

I am doing my stress test for N users using jmeter tool.

I have automated the test using ant and jenkins, my build file is configured to run a target i.e. the jmeter script.

It works fine.

Now i am trying to parameterize the jenkins i.e trying to pass the number of users "N" at the run time is there any way to get it done ?
Please advice.

Ant script:

```
<project basedir=".">
  <property environment="env"/>
  <property name="jmeter-home" location="D:/apache-jmeter-2.7"/>
  <path id="ant.jmeter.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${jmeter-home}/extras/ant-jmeter-1.0.9.jar" />
  </path>
  <taskdef name="jmeter" classname="org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.JMeterTask" classpathref="ant.jmeter.classpath" />
  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="results"/>
    <delete file="jmeter.log"/>
    <mkdir dir="results/jtl"/>
    <mkdir dir="results/html"/>
  </target>
```

Answer (score 1):

See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build . You can define a parameter for your job. Then you just need to pass it to the and with -Denv_entry=value (normal JVM Sswitch, you find it in advanced settings of Ant step in Jenkins), which can pass it to jmeter (see this article: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

EDIT:
You do not run JMeter in your ant script at all. So steps by step:

1. Call your ant script with: `-DTHREADS=value`
2. Ant script contains `<property environment="env"/>` correctly
3. Call JMeter with your task with giving JVM argument like this:

> ```
> <jmeter
>     jmeterhome="c:\jakarta-jmeter-1.8.1"
>     testplan="${basedir}/loadtests/JMeterLoadTest.jmx"
>     resultlog="${basedir}/loadtests/JMeterResults.jtl">
>   <jvmarg value="-Xincgc"/>
>   <jvmarg value="-Xmx128m"/>
>   <jvmarg value="-DTHREADS=${env.THREADS}"/>
> </jmeter>
> ```

Then you will have a system property in JMeter. If you want to have a JMeter property use -JTHREADS=${env.THREADS} instead.

EDIT2:
Add this:

```
<taskdef name="jvmarg" classname="org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.Arg" classpathref="ant.jmeter.classpath"/>
```

Then should work.

Comment: I tried using string parameter.
gave the name as THREADS.
and in the ANT part of jenkins I gave the Properties as
my.prop=${env.THREADS}


and in java options i declared the value as
-Denv_THREADS=value
after build now its asking for threads if give 3 its not picking it up.

Comment: In your ant script you can print out all properties with <echoproperties/>. Please check if your THREADS variable is there. However when you want to get an environment entry in Ant (see http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html), and you give an env entry like -DTHREADS=value, and you define <property environment="env"/> in ant, then this property will be available as env.THREADS. Try it please. If still does not work, please include a screenshot about your Ant build step config and your ant script as an edit of your post.

Comment: <project basedir=".">
   <property environment="env"/>
  <property name="jmeter-home" location="D:/apache-jmeter-2.7"/>
    <path id="ant.jmeter.classpath">
    <pathelement
       location="${jmeter-home}/extras/ant-jmeter-1.0.9.jar" />
  </path>
 <taskdef
    name="jmeter"
    classname="org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.JMeterTask"
    classpathref="ant.jmeter.classpath" />

  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="results"/>
    <delete file="jmeter.log"/>
    <mkdir dir="results/jtl"/>
    <mkdir dir="results/html"/>
    </target>
This is my ant script pls have a look.

Comment: I added the script into your question as an edit. If it will be reviewed, you will see it.

Comment: Given
String parameter name:THREADS
Invoke ANT:Properties as env.Threads
Java options as:-Denv.THREADS=value
not  picking up the thread value which i enter after build now is clicked.

Comment: D:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Exam\workspace\build.xml:27: Problem: failed to create task or type jvmarg
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
getting this error.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place

Comment: When I Add the task def its throwing this error.
No public execute() in class org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.Arg

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a nicer approach if you did not try to run the Jenkins job N times, but pass this N parameter into your ant script (see other answers on how to pass parameters into ant from jenkins) and make that deal with starting the tests in parallel N times.

Comment: I am new to ant and jenkins could some one help me to do this step by step i will be of great help
thanks in advance